# What is the difference between "appropriate" and "suitable"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is the difference between "appropriate" and "suitable"?

Answer (score 19):

In many contexts they are exactly equivalent. However *suitable* has the meaning of simply being usable for a particular purpose, while *appropriate* has additional connotations of being non-offensive, of the proper register, etc.

Comment: Precisely: *appropriate* carries a value judgment that *suitable* (mostly) lacks.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I'd say 'appropriate' makes more of a 'value judgement' on the part of the speaker.

Answer (score 7):

The definitions shown by the NOAD are the following:

- *suitable*: right or appropriate for a particular person, purpose, or situation
- *appropriate*: suitable or proper in the circumstances

The difference is that you say "these toys are not suitable for children under five" (appropriate for a particular person), but "a measure appropriate to a wartime economy" (proper in the circumstances). You can also say "this watch is suitable for scuba diving".

Answer (score 5):

Let's take kiamlaluno's example:

> This watch is suitable for scuba diving.

Let's say for example that the watch was given to you by your friend's recently-deceased father, and you are going diving with your friend. While the watch *suits the purpose* of scuba diving, it may not be *appropriate* to wear it while with this friend, as it reminds him of his father.